# joystick output not reliable

Tags: ros, navigation, teleop, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using joystick to drive turtlesim, he goes a ways then stops. If I move the stick a bit, he'll start up again. This may be a similar problem to seeing the numbers zero out when I run a full robot stack, with ROS_controls, and echo cmd_vel output to the terminal. Numbers look good for five seconds but then go to zero at unexpected times and at different stick angles. Is ROS failing me or is it the hardware? Using jstest the numbers stay looking good. Is it a problem with the publishing rate in hertz?

---

Edit:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="turtlesim" respawn="true"/>
    <node pkg="teleop_twist_joy" type="teleop_node" name="teleop_twist_joy">
        <remap from="cmd_vel" to="turtle1/cmd_vel"/>
    </node>
    <node pkg="joy" type="joy_node" name="joy_node"/>
</launch>
```

The above is for the turtlesim test. The stack for actual robot is RosJet from here: https://github.com/NVIDIAGPUTeachingKit/rosjet.

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279099/joystick-output-not-reliable/) by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2018-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-08**:
This sounds to me like a joystick device being opened in 'event mode' and using a motion controller with an integrated (and enabled) command time-out (ie: no new `Twist` in X sec -> stop).

Can you describe the full setup you have? Which nodes are involved in the teleop dataflow?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-09**:
I've moved your comments to your original question, as comments are not suited for showing launch files. Please always update your original question in these cases using the `edit` button/link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If that is your launch file, I believe you are missing some important parameters for this to work correctly.

The [launch file](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_joy/blob/3e39c1304b4351c61674c18d663b8befa4eef627/launch/teleop.launch) for `teleop_twist_joy` sets (among others) the `autorepeat_rate` parameter for the `joy_node` node, which is probably what is causing the issues here.

> Is it a problem with the publishing rate in hertz?

In a way: yes. Without `autorepeat_rate`, joysticks in event mode will not cause any msgs to be sent without any changes being detected to any of the axes. If you maintain stick position (ie: angles), nothing will change (due to filtering/deadzone), causing no msgs to be published. No messages -> auto stop (in well-written mobile base drivers, that is, see [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/138eb3b66a51261457fda764e0b5d3bb74a170e0/turtlesim/src/turtle.cpp#L146-L150) for how this is implemented in `turtlesim`).

From the [joy](http://wiki.ros.org/joy) wiki page:

> `~autorepeat_rate` (`double`, default: 0.0 (disabled))
>
> Rate in Hz at which a joystick that has a non-changing state will resend the previously sent message.

I would recommend to alter your launch file to `include` the `teleop_twist_joy/launch/teleop.launch` file, instead of starting the node directly (note that you also don't need to start the `joy_node` itself anymore in that case). That will set all parameters as they should be, and things should start working a whole lot better. See also the [teleop_twist_joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy) documentation on the ROS wiki.

Including provided launch files is in general always a good strategy btw, as typically launch files configure parameters that the node needs. Defaults can work, but they are always going to be sub-optimal.

---

Edit: and if you want to go a step further, you could look into including some of the packages from the Turtlebot, such as [yocs_cmd_vel_mux](http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_cmd_vel_mux) (multiplexing between different `Twist` sources) and [yocs_velocity_smoother](http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_velocity_smoother) (filter for `Twist` inputs).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-01-10**:
That makes sense! I'll try this out as soon as I get back to the robot shop. Thanks!

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-01-10**:
Yes, that was it. Added two lines of parameters and it works perfectly. Thanks. I removed those lines earlier (from joy and teleop launch sections) because the software wouldn't work at all, and after removing the parameters, it started working for the first time.

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-01-10**:
Now I need to figure out why the motor commands from the Arduino often contain garbage and therefore don't control the motors well. Maybe it's because the encoders aren't connected up yet.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-11**:
That would seem to be a different issue.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-11**:\

> Added two lines of parameters and it works perfectly.

note btw that the `teleop_twist_joy` launch file does more: it also loads a yaml file that configures `teleop_twist_joy` with quite some additional parameters.

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-01-14**:
Got the motors to perform! Turns out the Sabertooth Arduino libraries are not compatible with ROS. Program the direct serial writes instead and you're good to go.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-05-02**:
This helped me a lot! Thanks @gvdhoorn.